# No module named 'torch.utils.data.distributed'

Tags: python, anaconda, pytorch

I have installed anaconda and pytorch on my windows 10 and there was no errors when I installed it.

But I don't know why I don't have the modules or packages in pytorch.
Have you experienced the same problem?

This is the program I'm testing: https://github.com/pytorch/examples/blob/master/imagenet/main.py

Answer (score 2):

Because you didn't provide any additional information, there are couple of things you can try:

1) first make sure that you've already installed `torchvision`

2) Then try the following import:

```
# this import is necessary
import torch.utils.data
```

Comment: Thanks.But I have installed torchvision.And this is my import:import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.parallel
import torch.backends.cudnn as cudnn
import torch.distributed as dist
import torch.optim
import torch.utils.data
import torch.utils.data.distributed
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
import torchvision.datasets as datasets
import torchvision.models as models